# Transforming *& to just a pointer

Tags: c++11, call, asterisk, yacc, ampersand

```
"no matching function for call to [...] cdk::sequence_node*&"
```

What kind of sorcery is this? How do I fix it? Do I have to cast?

Function expects `cdk::sequence_node * some_sequence_node` as argument.

According to this question about [asterisk and ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314640/both-asterisk-and-ampersand-in-a-parameter-c)

> BinaryNode b;
>
> BinaryNode* ptr = &b;
>
> BinaryNode* &t  = ptr;

Why is the compiler complaining if `BinaryNode* &t  = ptr;`?
Edit (as requested):

```
pwn_parser.y: In function ‘int yyparse(std::shared_ptr<cdk::compiler>)’:
pwn_parser.y:70:135: error: no matching function for call to ‘pwn::func_decl_node::func_decl_node(int, bool, bool, basic_type*&, std::string*&, cdk::sequence_node*&)’
 func_decl : type_specifier tIDENTIFIER '(' func_decl_args ')' context { $$ = new pwn::func_decl_node(LINE, false, false, $1, $2, $4); }

pwn_parser.y:70:135: note: candidates are:

In file included from ast/all.h:99:0,
                 from pwn_parser.y:5:
./ast/func_decl_node.h:29:12: note: pwn::func_decl_node::func_decl_node(int, bool, bool, basic_type*, cdk::identifier_node*, cdk::sequence_node*)
     inline func_decl_node(int lineno, bool local, bool import,
```

Comment: It's likely some other part of the signature that didn't match, but you didn't show the true code, nor the entire error message, nor the list of candidates that the compiler likely gave, so our hands are tied.

Comment: `&t = ptr` doesn't make much sense. 'the address of the variable "t" is the value stored in the variable "ptr"'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032461/convert-reference-to-pointer-representation-in-c

Comment: *Edited - Thank you for the replies :D Have to finish project by tomorrow. Murphy's law <3

Comment: Comparing the function signature to the arguments, the second to last argument seems to be missing - or is there another overload?

Comment: 6 arguments in signature, 6 arguments in call

Comment: Oops, correct. However, you're passing a `std::string*` where a `identifier_node*` is expected (for the overload shown by the compiler as a candidate).

Comment: The `&` in the argument list ("`no matching function for call to '[...] basic_type*&`") usually denote the *value category* of the argument expression you have used for the call. E.g. for `void foo(vector<int>);`, a call `foo(42)` would report `no matching function for call 'foo(int)'` whereas a call `int i = 42; foo(i)` would report `no matching function for call 'foo(int&)'`.

Comment: Oh wow that solved it! Thank you very much dyp! :D Guess I got so scared by that  *& dark magic that I overlooked the more simple problem. :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dyp, who helped me notice a little mismatch that I had overlooked, I was able to fix it.

> Oops, correct. However, you're passing a std::string* where a identifier_node* is expected (for the overload shown by the compiler as a candidate). - by dyp

Lesson 1: Don't make the mistake of looking at a problem as if it was a huge monster or fire blowing wide winged dragon blocking your way. Picture the problem as always being smaller than yourself. [Funny Awkward Yeti Comic](http://theawkwardyeti.com/comic/challenge-accepted/)

Lesson 2: Don't make the assumption that some part of the information is irrelevant.